# #property in CSS? what does it mean?

Tags: css, dojo

I've come across some CSS in dojo that I've never seen before. They used the `#` in the property name in the css..

```
.dijitInline {
  #zoom: 1;
}
```

What does that `#` in front of `zoom` mean?

Answer (score 2):

Using `#zoom` is technically invalid css that is sometimes used as an IE fix solution. It's best to avoid adding `#` to your CSS properties.

Comment: can you elaborate on what this does for IE?